# Text and image blur when I flip the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, catransform3d

I have an application in which i need to **flip the UIView Horizontally (180 degrees)**. This **UIView** also contains **UILabel** and **UIImageView**.

I use this code to flip the UIView and again flip the UILabel and UIImageView to avoid mirror effect.

```
-(void)rotateSearchView:(UIView *)searchView{

    searchView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    searchView.frame = CGRectIntegral(searchView.frame);
    for(UIView *view in searchView.subviews){

        view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        view.frame = CGRectIntegral(view.frame);
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){

            UITextField *lbl = (UITextField *) view;
            [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
        }
    }
}
```

But now the text in UILabel and image in UIImageView is blurry.

Any suggestions

Comment: why are you touching the searchView subviews ?

Comment: the search view is custom created by me.

Answer (score 0):

You first flip your superview named "searchView". Then you flip all subviews of that superview. The flip of the superview flips also the subviews tough. Try only flipping your superview.

Comment: Yes the first flip also flips the subviews but then the text and images are inverted, so to get them to their orignal form i need to flip the subviews again